# Calculating DynamoDB RCU pricing per day (not per second)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If we ignore storage capacity, writes, strongly-consistent reads, and transactional reads, and assume that our app can only perform eventually-consistent reads, is the following true?

1 RCU = 1 eventual 8K read per second

Therefore, 1 RCU = 86,400 eventual 8K reads per day

With 25 free RCU's = 2.16 million eventual 8K reads per day FREE

Or 2.16 million free RCU's per day

If the average query reads 200 items @ 0.5k per item = 13 RCU's

Assuming they do nothing else on the app, 166,153 people can make that one and only query every day for free?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if those 166,153 people make that call once a day but also never at the same time (if you have multiple calls per second and you provisioned 25 RCU, calls exceeding 25 RCU will be throttled).