# How to find total hits on DynamoDB table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a Lambda function that is hitting DynamoDB and getting values from there. I wanted to check if there is any way where I can see how many times lambda hits the DynamoDB table. I tried to see in CloudWatch but unable to find it.

Comment: What operation does the lambda use? query, scan, get item, or batch get item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do it.
You can use read/write capacity metrics for the table if the lambda is the only consumer of this table

Under Dynamodb -> you table -> Metrics, or from CW Metrics

[image]

And calculate a measurement of the actions according to this topic:
[How are consumed read capacity units calculated in DynamoDB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178275/how-are-consumed-read-capacity-units-calculated-in-dynamodb-query)

Currently, AWS doesn't show these metrics that you asked for

Answer (score 0):

If you own the source code behind the Lambda, then you can get it to emit a metric everytime a DDB call is made (or when the DDB call fails).

You can read more about Custom metrics here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html